# Cannot find the embedded schemas in the assembly

Tags: c#, xsd, .net-assembly

I have DefaultSchemaSet.xsd. Now I'm getting FileNotFoundException for the codes below. Give me any suggestion, please? May I know how to solve this?

```
public static void GetDefaultSchemas(string path, XmlSchemaSet schemas, ValidationEventHandler schemaValidationEventHandler)
    {
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(path))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find the embedded schemas in the assembly!");
            }

            var schema = XmlSchema.Read(stream, schemaValidationEventHandler);
            schemas.Add(schema);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the format of the resource name:

```
DefaultNamespace[.Subfolder][...MoreSubfolers].FileName[.extension]
```

You need to set Build Action to Embedded Resource in project's file's properties.

[image: Embedded resource]

Also, you need to check the namespace you use for your project:
[image]

Try to examine the available resources, so you can find if a particular one present:

```
        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceNames = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resource: " + resourceName);
            Console.WriteLine("Contents:");
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
Resource: EmbeddingTests.TextFile1.txt
Contents:
Hello
Resource: EmbeddingTests.NewFolder1.TextFile2.txt
Contents:
Hello 2
```

Comment: Thanks you George. I solved the problem by following your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure you can access it from your code you need to ensure that the file's build action is set to "Embedded Resource"

To help further we really need to see where the file lies in your solution (to give you an exact answer), however in the mean time if you ensure that your parameter "path" follows the pattern:

```
[DefaultNamespace].[AnySubFolders].[filename.fileextension]
```

**note** without the square brackets

Comment: it's not the assembly name which forms the resource name, it's project's default namespace